# Layout tab showing a blank rectangle

Tags: rendering

[image]

the layout tab only shows a black rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal if you only have that one texture. Once you create a new texture, or import an image, it will show up in that "black rectangle" and you will be able to use it. For reference: this box is not for shaders, it is for textures.

Comment: I had a model I made i switched over to the modeling tab and now it won't show up anymore.

Comment: You are in the UV editor workspace, Try switching to image editor ?

Comment: UV and Image editor are the same.